# psycopg2 cursor.execute() pass in variable table names and items

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I was trying to get a certain group of objects from a specific table in a postgres database using psycopg2. all the advice I had seen on passing variables to a cursor.execute(SQL) command did not seem to work with two types of variables

this was what I tired first that didn't work:

```
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM %s WHERE created_on < date (%s);'
cursor.execute(SQL,[(table_name), (time_from)])
```

this always returned a syntax error where the table_name was inserted

Comment: Search for 'AsIs' in the psycopg2 docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Antoine's comment, the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) now suggests this method for composing table names.

```
from psycopg2 import sql

cur.execute(
sql.SQL("insert into {} values (%s, %s)")
    .format(sql.Identifier('my_table')),
[10, 20])
```

Answer (score -2):

this was my solution:

```
SQL1 = 'SELECT * FROM %s' %table_name
SQL2 = SQL1+' WHERE created_on < date (%s);'
cursor.execute(SQL2, (time_from, ))
```

The table names cannot be passed the normal way because they get converted to an object within the SQL command

Comment: As stated in psycopg2 documentation: "**Warning**: Never, **never, NEVER** use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint. " You should use the new SQL module: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql

Comment: Why is this the approved answer?